# Is there a way to decrease a value while counting objects using a Pi camera?

Tags: java, android, python

I'm currently doing a college project counting objects using a camera on a Pi. When an object is detected I need to decrease the 100 count by 1 each time an object is detected. I'm using open CV but I do not require camera feed. When an object is picked up , I need the value of `qtty_of_count` to be decreased by one and this value is then sent to a firebase database. Is the `qtty_of_count - 1` in the incorrect place? Please help.

```
import datetime
import math
import cv2
import numpy as np

import firebase
##from firebase import firebase



# global variables
from firebase.firebase import FirebaseApplication

width = 0
height = 0
EntranceCounter = 0
ExitCounter = 0
min_area = 3000  # Adjust ths value according to your usage
_threshold = 70  # Adjust ths value according to your usage
OffsetRefLines = 150  # Adjust ths value according to your usage


# Check if an object in entering in monitored zone
def check_entrance_line_crossing(y, coor_y_entrance, coor_y_exit):
    abs_distance = abs(y - coor_y_entrance)

    if ((abs_distance <= 2) and (y < coor_y_exit)):
        return 1
    else:
        return 0


# Check if an object in exitting from monitored zone
def check_exit_line_crossing(y, coor_y_entrance, coor_y_exit):
    abs_distance = abs(y - coor_y_exit)

    if ((abs_distance <= 2) and (y > coor_y_entrance)):
        return 1
    else:
        return 0


camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

# force 640x480 webcam resolution
camera.set(3, 640)
camera.set(4, 480)

ReferenceFrame = None

# Frames may discard while adjusting to light
for i in range(0, 20):
    (grabbed, Frame) = camera.read()

while True:
    (grabbed, Frame) = camera.read()
    height = np.size(Frame, 0)
    width = np.size(Frame, 1)

    # if cannot grab a frame, this program ends here.
    if not grabbed:
        break

    # gray-scale and Gaussian blur filter applying
    GrayFrame = cv2.cvtColor(Frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    GrayFrame = cv2.GaussianBlur(GrayFrame, (21, 21), 0)

    if ReferenceFrame is None:
        ReferenceFrame = GrayFrame
        continue

    # Background subtraction and image manipulation
    FrameDelta = cv2.absdiff(ReferenceFrame, GrayFrame)
    FrameThresh = cv2.threshold(FrameDelta, _threshold, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]

    # Dilate image and find all the contours
    FrameThresh = cv2.dilate(FrameThresh, None, iterations=2)
    cnts, _ = cv2.findContours(FrameThresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    qtty_of_count =100

    # plot reference lines (entrance and exit lines)
    coor_y_entrance = (height // 2) - OffsetRefLines
    coor_y_exit = (height // 2) + OffsetRefLines
    cv2.line(Frame, (0, coor_y_entrance), (width, coor_y_entrance), (255, 0, 0), 2)
    cv2.line(Frame, (0, coor_y_exit), (width, coor_y_exit), (0, 0, 255), 2)

    # check all found count
    for c in cnts:
        # if a contour has small area, it'll be ignored
        if cv2.contourArea(c) < min_area:
            continue

        qtty_of_count = qtty_of_count - 1
        app = FirebaseApplication('https://appproject-d5d51.firebaseio.com/', None)
        update = app.put('/car', "spaces", qtty_of_count)
        print("Updated value in FB value: " + str(update))
        (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(c)
        cv2.rectangle(Frame, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 2)

        # find object's centroid
        coor_x_centroid = (x + x + w) // 2
        coor_y_centroid = (y + y + h) // 2
        ObjectCentroid = (coor_x_centroid, coor_y_centroid)
        cv2.circle(Frame, ObjectCentroid, 1, (0, 0, 0), 5)

        if (check_entrance_line_crossing(coor_y_centroid, coor_y_entrance, coor_y_exit)):
            EntranceCounter += 1

        if (check_exit_line_crossing(coor_y_centroid, coor_y_entrance, coor_y_exit)):
            ExitCounter += 1

print("Total countours found: " + str(qtty_of_count))

# Write entrance and exit counter values on frame and shows it
cv2.putText(Frame, "Entrances: {}".format(str(EntranceCounter)), (10, 50),
            cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (250, 0, 1), 2)
cv2.putText(Frame, "Exits: {}".format(str(ExitCounter)), (10, 70),
            cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (0, 0, 255), 2)
cv2.imshow("Original Frame", Frame)
cv2.waitKey(1)

# cleanup the camera and close any open windows
camera.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I need the `qtty_of_count` to decrease by one every time an object is detected. Thank you.

Comment: `qtty_of_count = qtty_of_count - 1` is indeed a valid way of reducing `qtty_of_count` by one. What leads you to believe that it's not decreasing?

Comment: With the code I have, it is only decreasing if more than one object is obtained by the camera, so if one is recognized it becomes 99 but if another moves past it stays at 99? Then if two moves it decreases to 98. Have I the complete wrong code? I have very little experience with Python.

Comment: I'm not familiar with computer vision libraries, so I don't completely understand your program logic... But here's my random guess: try moving `qtty_of_count =100` to the line just above `while True:`.

Comment: Okay that worked it is now decreasing one at a time, but now instead of decreasing as an object is detected, as soon as one is it just constantly counts down. from 100-0

Answer (score 0):

Besides the problem indicated by @Kevin, your code is executing the evaluation on image every frame that you grabed. If your object stays there for 100 frames, your count will go to zero.

To overcome this, you should tag every object in the image and just count the new objects. This could be done in several ways (see kalman filter tracking), but with no occulsion situation, one simple solution might be store the x,y position of object and establish a maximum position deviation to keep the tag to that object.

Comment: I'm currently running the Program on PyCharm and my laptops webcam is acting as the camera, I'm not getting any visual feedback of the image being read so I'm not sure how to tag recognized objects etc. Is there a simpler way to do this? I don't need a live feed just an object to be recognized. The logic behind it is that the program presumes movement is a car as the project is only a proof of concept? Thanks.

Comment: So when you identify the object for the first time: take x,y position of object, give it a name, store it (in a python dictionary, for example). In the next frames, when you identify it again: check if it x,y position is stored and just count if do not.

Comment: Is there a way around storing? Any movement picked up I am making the assumption that it is a value I need to count. The code is working at the minute counting a single object but sometimes the code constantly takes one away when nothing is actually moving. Like I said, this is a proof of concept of how it SHOULD work if done with a longer time period and extended knowledge on Python. My error has pretty much been fixed. I was just wondering if I was missing something that may allow for the code to run more efficiently.

Comment: In this case, you need to refresh your ReferenceFrame. Your code are identifying the same object in every interaction. When you identify the object, refresh your ReferenceFrame. But, I would start working with other background substraction techniques from the same opencv package. Many of those already do the automatic refresh of ReferencFrame (https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d7/df6/classcv_1_1BackgroundSubtractor.html)